# Would these two queries yield the same result (Using Window Function vs Group By)

Tags: mysql, sql

I came across this question in "Ace the Data Science Interview":

"Assume you are given the table below containing information on user purchases. Write a query to obtain the number of people who purchased at least one or more of the same product on multiple days."

**purchases**

| column_name | type |
| --- | --- |
| purchase_id | integer |
| user_id | integer |
| product_id | integer |
| quantity | integer |
| price | float |
| purchase_time | datetime |

I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT 
    count(DISTINCT user_id) as num_ppl_w_multiple_purchases
FROM (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        count(*) as num_product_purchases /* only increments for purchases made on different days */
    FROM
        purchases
    GROUP BY
        user_id,
        product_id,
        DATE(purchase_time)
    HAVING
        num_product_purchases > 1
) t
```

And the book provides this solution:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            user_id,
            RANK() OVER (
                PARTITION BY user_id,
                product_id
                ORDER BY
                    CAST(purchase_time as DATE)
            ) AS purchase_no
        FROM
            purchases
    ) t
WHERE
    purchase_no = 2
```

I have no way to verify if these two queries achieve the same thing. Could someone give me affirmation that my query is correct and if it isn't why not?

---

EDIT
Modified query in response to Bill Karwin's response:

```
SELECT 
    count(DISTINCT user_id) as num_ppl_w_multiple_purchases
FROM (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        count(*) as num_product_purchases
    FROM (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT user_id, product_id, DATE(purchase_time)
        FROM
            purchases
    ) t1
    GROUP BY
        user_id,
        product_id
    HAVING
        num_product_purchases > 1
) t2
```

Comment: Did you try them? Thats the best way to answer this question..... yourself

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk is a great trial and succeed place

Comment: Or even a fiddle that uses [Mysql](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Because I don't have data and I don't want to manually create a bunch of dummy data thinking about edge cases. Thought that was pretty obvious.

Comment: But of course you are happy for us to create data so we can test our answer before giving it :) That ok is it?

Comment: No, I never said I expected someone to do that. Maybe there was some SQL guru out there that could tell me why they are or aren't the same simply by inspection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks like it would match a user who bought the same product multiple times on the *same* day, but it would not find users who bought the same product on multiple days. Your GROUP BY criteria include the date, so the count will only include those entries per date.

```
+-------------+---------+------------+----------+-------+---------------------+
| purchase_id | user_id | product_id | quantity | price | purchase_time       |
+-------------+---------+------------+----------+-------+---------------------+
|           1 |       2 |         10 |        1 |    10 | 2022-04-20 00:00:00 |
|           2 |       2 |         10 |        1 |    10 | 2022-04-21 00:00:00 |
|           3 |       8 |         10 |        1 |    10 | 2022-04-19 00:00:00 |
|           4 |       8 |         10 |        1 |    10 | 2022-04-19 00:00:00 |
+-------------+---------+------------+----------+-------+---------------------+
```

I'll demonstrate by using part of your subquery:

```
SELECT user_id, date(purchase_time), count(*) as num_product_purchases 
FROM purchases GROUP BY user_id, product_id, DATE(purchase_time);

+---------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| user_id | date(purchase_time) | num_product_purchases |
+---------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|       2 | 2022-04-20          |                     1 |
|       2 | 2022-04-21          |                     1 |
|       8 | 2022-04-19          |                     2 |
+---------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

The user 2 has made purchases on two separate days, but since each day is in its own group, they are both counted as 1. So they will be excluded by the HAVING condition. Only user 8 gets a count of 2, because they purchased their product on the *same* day.

But user 8 should *not* be counted as having purchased the product on multiple days, because they only purchased on one day. So the results are wrong for both users.

---

The results from testing your updated query (just part of the subquery so we can see the interim result):

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) as num_product_purchases FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT user_id, product_id, DATE(purchase_time) FROM purchases) t1 
GROUP BY user_id, product_id;

+---------+-----------------------+
| user_id | num_product_purchases |
+---------+-----------------------+
|       2 |                     2 |
|       8 |                     1 |
+---------+-----------------------+
```

That looks better. I can't think of another data sample that would make this wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for catching the error in my original query. I'm wondering if the query can be done without use of a window function. I added another query in my edit in the question which may do the trick.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just group on user_id and product_id and return the results having count(distinct purchase_date)?  It doesn't seem to require a subquery.  Also, his dates are stored as datetimes but are all dates, so the date() isn't necessary, and the question is really to get the count of users, not the list of users and products, so the final query should have count distinct user_id.  Am I missing something?  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=93a4c40e307088ebff405910d885f200

Comment: @ChrisStrickland, your solution is not sufficient, because if you group by user_id and also count(distinct user_id) in the same query level (i.e. not in a subquery), you are bound to get a set of rows, each counting a single user, not the overall count of matching users.

Comment: right, the problem was apparent as soon as I modified the data to include multiple user_ids matching the criteria.